# Forwarding HTTP/HTTPS traffic based on URL

Tags: iis-7, http, https, url-routing

I look for a solution to forward http/https traffic to a backend webserver based on the request url. Our current setup:

- Webserver1 (Sharepoint)
- Webserver2 (Reporting Services)

Both run Windows Server 2008 and IIS7. The Webserver1 receives all traffic on port 80 and 443 and hosts a website called www.example.com

Now I want the Webserver2 to be accessible as www.example.com/Reports. Unfortunately we do not have any advanced edge firewall that could route traffic based on the request url. So I wonder if there is a way to configure Webserver1 to forward all traffic if it matches www.example.com/Reports. Any way IIS7 could do this?

Suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS7 has a [URL rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) module, which, along with the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/extensions/ApplicationRequestRouting) module, based on the URL, can be used to do what you want.

You build it all up in the UI, and it then automatically build the XML and puts it in the web.config for you.

See "Reverse proxy" (number 7) on [this list](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it seems ARR fails as soon as I use NTLM authentication over HTTP :(

Comment: "[U]nless you need to do authorization on the router machine, you should turn off windows auth on it and only enable anonymous auth - this will make ARR just pass the challenges/credentials along to the backend machine." - http://forums.iis.net/t/1150821.aspx  You could do it just for the one virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do a URL redirection to a different port number.

So set up www.example.com/Reports as a virtual directory on web server 1, but have it url redirect to www.example.com:444/Reports.  It's possible you might need to change the domain name that it redirects to.

I'll be interested to see how it works and if I missed any steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to the one I had: [Forwarding hostheaders](https://serverfault.com/questions/23885/forwarding-hostheaders)

I ended up paying for the "ISAPI_Rewrite" filter, witch I'm sure can do what you want.

The only issue is that you have to do a little RegEx magic, witch I find a bit difficult.